# How to record requests during testing Javascript crawler (Capybara + Poltergeist) in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, web-crawler, vcr

I am using Capybara + Poltergeist as replacement for Mechanize.

Mechanize doesn't support Javascript and I want to scrap page which heavily uses JS and iframes.

I am using similiar approach to this:
http://www.chadcf.com/blog/using-capybara-javascript-capable-replacement-mechanize

But I haven't found resources how to record requests in VCR for Capybara.

Simple recording `vcr: true` doesnt works...

Any thoughts?